# Can I make a Python if condition using Regex on Pandas column to see if it contains something and then create a new column to hold it

Tags: python, pandas, regex

Say I have data like this

|  | Account |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Kevin (1234567) |
| 2 | Buzz (7896345) |
| 3 | Snakes (5438761) |
| 4 | Marv |
| 5 | Harry (9083213) |

I want to use an if condition to search to see if the account number exists at the end of the name in the account column, if it does split the account number off and put it in a new column, if not pass and go on to the next Account.

Something like this although it does not work

```
dataset.loc[dataset.Account.str.contains(r'\(d+')], 'new'=dataset.Account.str.split('',n=1, expand=True)
dataset["Account_Number"] = new[1]
```

Comment: @lucas_7_94 yes I was thinking just leaving it Na

Comment: To match digits, you need `\d+`, not `d+`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["Account number"] = df["Account"].str.extract(r"\((\d+)\)$")
df["Account"] = df["Account"].str.replace(r"\s*\(\d+\)$", "", regex=True)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Account Account number
1   Kevin        1234567
2    Buzz        7896345
3  Snakes        5438761
4    Marv            NaN
5   Harry        9083213
```

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to do it

```
# split the account on ( and create two columns
df[['Account','Account Number']]= df['Account'].str.split('(', expand=True)

#replace the trailing ) with empty string
df['Account Number']=df['Account Number'].str.replace(r'\)','', regex=True ).str.strip()
df
dfdf
```

```
        Account     Account Number
0   1   Kevin              1234567
1   2   Buzz               7896345
2   3   Snakes             5438761
3   4   Marv                  None
4   5   Harry              9083213
```